# How to merge two arrays in Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, concatenation

According to [JS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) there a concat() method for concatenating arrays, but if I try it in angular:

```
$scope.array1 = [];
$scope.array2 = [];

$scope.myConcatenatedData = array1 .concat(array2);
```

I got an error: `ReferenceError: array1 is not defined` because I don't use var in declaring arrays.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The arrays are defined on the scope object so you need to do this:

```
$scope.myConcatenatedData = $scope.array1.concat($scope.array2);
```